# Помогите разобраться с QCompleter в PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2, qcompleter

Такой вопрос у меня есть список:

```
b = ['красный карандаш', 'ручка красная', 'фломастер красный', 'зеленый карандаш']
```

Я хочу чтобы когда я ввожу слово красный, он мне предлагал в выпадающем окне похожих слов все из этого списка в которых есть слово красный, сейчас вот этот код выдает только красный карандаш

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QCompleter, QWidget

b = ['красный карандаш', 'ручка красная', 'фломастер красный']

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QWidget()
win.setWindowTitle('ffff')
win.resize(300, 300)
text = QLineEdit(win)
com = QCompleter(b, win)
text.setCompleter(com)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо установить режим фильтра в [Qt.MatchContains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum) (По умолчанию `Qt.MatchStartsWith`):

```py
import PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

...

com = QCompleter(b, win)

# Устанавливаем режим поиска слов
com.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)

# Если надо отключить чувствительность к регистру вводимых букв
com.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

text.setCompleter(com)

...
```

Comment: А можете это в коде изменить, как это сделать, просто я попробовал не получилось

Comment: @Tesla подправил. У меня все работает ) Не забывайте про регистр вводимых букв (добавил, чтобы это не имело значения)

Comment: Супер, спасибо вам за потраченное время

Comment: А еще можно последний вопрос, если какой нибудь метод, который выдает список 5 наиболее часто вводимых и этот список в выпадает как только поле ввода становиться активным

Comment: @Tesla наиболее часто вводимых? Практически уверен, что "из коробки" такого нет и надо писать самому (надо ведь хранить вводимые значения и вести их подсчет). Насчет того, чтобы список был активным надо использовать QComboBox у которого есть метод showPopup, который вы можете вызвать при получении фокуса (скорее всего придется наследоваться и переопределять метод `focusInEvent`), хотя может быть есть какой-нибудь флажок - надо смотреть мануал

Comment: Хорошо спасибо большое

Comment: @Tesla насчет QComboBox - проверьте, кажется у него выпадает список элементов по умолчанию при получении фокуса